# How to render a view as XML in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-5

**sitemap.index** looks like this:

```
<?php
    use Vanilo\Product\Models\Product;
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<?php Product::all()->each(function($product) {
        echo "<url><loc>";
        echo route('product.show', $product);
        echo "</loc><lastmod>";
        echo \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        echo "</lastmod><changefreq>monthly</changefreq><priority>0.8</priority$
}); ?>

</urlset>
```

**web.php** looks like this where my route is:

```
Route::get('/sitemap', function() {
        return view('sitemap.index')->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'
        ]);
});
```

However, My page comes out like this:

```
https://evosmedia.uk/shop/p/blk-med-tshirt2019-07-21 08:33:54monthly0.8https://evosmedia.uk/shop/p/small-black-tshirt2019-07-21 08:33:54monthly0.8
```

How can I render the route as XML?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve it by using `Response::make()` and supplying the `View::make()`

```
Route::get('/sitemap', function() {
        $contents = View::make('sitemap.index');
        $response = Response::make($contents, 200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        return $response;
});
```